# Simple caching mechanism using hashmap and syncronized method call

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

We have a simple caching mechanism using HashMaps and syncronized load method. This is for a WAS 8 application server. Application consists of several web applications and web methods using JPA in background.

Since yesterday it was working nicely and had no problems. But got a major downtime. Reason was during some high traffic of webservices, lots of loadData method calls occured. I believe maps were null by that time, and every call tried to execute loaddata method even if first call loaded map.

A simple workaround came to my mind is seperately calling each load method synchronized seperately. But ultimately i believe we need a better solution since this will only lessen the chances that this will occur again.

I am aware there are some apis for caching, and willing to dig into more. But i believe there is a/some good solution without an api.

So, what would you suggest for this situation?

**Edit:** loadData method is only called from a servlet manually if cache needs to reloaded.

```
    private static HashMap<String, Long> someObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
private static HashMap<String, Long> someAnotherObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();


public synchronized static void loadData() {
    loadSomeObjectMap();
    loadSomeAnotherObjectMap();
            // and some more methods similar, about 10 of them
}

//fill first map
public static void loadSomeObjectMap (){
    someObjectMap = null;
    try {
        if (someObjectMap == null ) {
            someObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            //fill someObjectMap here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Util.getStackTrace(e));
    }       
}
//fill second map
public static void loadSomeAnotherObjectMap (){
    someAnotherObjectMap = null;
    try {
        if (someAnotherObjectMap == null ) {
            someAnotherObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            //fill someObjectMap here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Util.getStackTrace(e));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot I find odd with your code. For example:

#### One:

```
someObjectMap = null;
try {
    if (someObjectMap == null ) {
```

What point is there to set a variable to `null` and then immediately *test* if it's `null`? And all that while holding a lock?

#### Two:

```
public static void loadSomeObjectMap (){
```

Why is this method public? Calling it directly will circumvent synchronization and present a textbook example of a data race.

#### Three:

At which point do you call `loadData`? Is it a scheduled task, which refreshes the caches at set intervals? That's how it *should* be, but from your question it appears that it is being called at each service call. You may be using a lazy initialization scheme, but there is no evidence of that in your code.

#### About your comment on using an industrial-grade caching library:

Yes, you should definitely use it. What you are doing now is nothing but a learning experience to convince you of that. Along the way you'll meet out-of-memory issues, locking issues, GC issues, database issues... to name a few off the top of my head.

Comment: Ok good points. But i have some explanations i believe. One: There is a chance that map is nullified outside since its not locked. That comes to point Two: there is only one place this is called actually. A servlet to null all values so cache can be reloaded without a restart. This is why method is public, its called from outside.Three is also answered since its only on server start or servlet call. I am not saying this is the right way to do it but thats how it works currently.

Comment: But you definitely *must not* either read or write to those maps without locking, otherwise you have a data race.

Comment: You are right about writing with locks. But locking an object used for caching everytime to read sounds not reasonable. Using a concurrent map and locking only when writing seems a better solution, am i wrong?

Comment: If you want to go that route, then you need to carefully implement the proper singleton lazy initialization idiom.

Answer (score 0):

lock object instead of using synchronized method

example

```
private static final Object lockObject = new Object();
private static HashMap<String, Long> someObjectMap = null;

public static void loadSomeObjectMap (){
    lock(lockObject){
        try {
        if (someObjectMap == null ) {
                someObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
                //fill someObjectMap here
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(Util.getStackTrace(e));
        }  
    }     
}
```

or use a simple singleton

```
private static HashMap<String, Long> someObjectMap = null;

public static void loadSomeObjectMap (){            
    if (someObjectMap == null ) {
        try {
            someObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            //fill someObjectMap here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            someObjectMap = null ;
            logger.error(Util.getStackTrace(e));
        }              
    }     
}
```

Comment: I dont see how your second example different than mine current one. Only changing where map is nullified. Reason i null it in the beginning is that method is called when is already null or when it needs to be reloaded (that info wasnt in my question btw)

Comment: @ouzture it was posted at the same time i think... i agree with you, there are no differences